# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client while adding # throgh acsx contril

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am passing a value like "abc#abc" through one of the ascx controls.
But, Its firing an issue -

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (HotelCtrl:_ctl62:_ctl0:XmlsplSummary:_ctl23:_ctl2:HotelSme="abc#abc").
Description: ASP.NET has detected data in the request that is potentially dangerous because it might include HTML markup or script. The data might represent an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. If this type of input is appropriate in your application, you can include code in a web page to explicitly allow it. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212874.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (HotelControl:_ctl62:_ctl0:XmlSupplierSummary:_ctl23:_ctl2:HotelSme="abc#abc").

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\tanweb\c2c4a012\beafc832\App_Web_htl.aspx.c5eca4cb.hre0kuii.0.cs    Line: 0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use html encoding, it's a potentially dangerous request because it can be used for sql injection etc etc. So the solution is turn off the checks(definitely not recommended) or encode the text to html.

Hope that make sense.